# VolleyのJsonObjectRequestの引数について

Tags: android, android-volley

[こちら](http://techbooster.org/android/hacks/16474/)のサイトを参考にしてVolleyによるHTTP通信を実装したのですが｡画像のように引数が間違っていると出てしまいます｡  調べてみたのですがどこのサイトも上のサイトと同じ引数を使用しているので､Volleyの仕様が変更になったのでしょうか｡[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]  VolleyのJsonObjectRequestを確認したところ､次のようなコードになっていたのですが､なぜかUrlがint型になっているのですが､これはバグか何かですか?

```
/**
 * Constructor which defaults to <code>GET</code> if <code>jsonRequest</code> is
 * <code>null</code>, <code>POST</code> otherwise.
 *
 * @see #JsonObjectRequest(int, String, JSONObject, Listener, ErrorListener)
 */
public JsonObjectRequest(int url, String jsonRequest, Listener<JSONObject> listener,
        Listener<JSONObject> errorListener) {
    this(jsonRequest == null ? Method.GET : Method.POST, url, jsonRequest,
            listener, errorListener);
}
```

Comment: もし仕様変更でしたら､新しい仕様について説明されているサイト等ありましたら教えていただけると幸いです｡

Comment: 引数の数があっているかどうかがこのスクリーンショットではわからないので、もう少し大きめでスクリーンショットを取り直していただけないでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

すいません自己解決いたしました｡ 引数を1つ忘れていました｡

Answer (score 1):

参考先のサイトのコードをそのまま利用して試してみましたがコードに問題はありませんでした。
エラーが出ている原因は必要なクラスがimportされていないためだと思われます。